# How fix CSS backdrop-filter blur in Slick slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, css-filters

I'm using this CSS for slides in Slick slider:

```css
backdrop-filter: blur(10px)
```

However, when I click to display the next slide, the CSS blur disappears for a second and then the slide blurs again. When dragging the slides with my mouse, the CSS blur disappears on mouseup.

How can I fix this?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/maxbeat/pen/abNBrex

```css
.slider__item {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font: 24px arial;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/assafcolli/pen/VwaPQgo).

You can use filter blur and then it will be smoothly:

```
filter: blur(1px);
```

Also, You need to split between the slide "shadow" layer and the slide "content" layer, as you want the content to be sharp and only the box background to be blurred.

Comment: That does keep the blur during slide change, however it blurs the contents of the slide as well.

Comment: It's can be fixed, he just needs to split the layers. Slider item with blur should be zIndex 0 (just for the example) and then the content should be on top of that - zIndex 1.

Comment: And another thing, see the browser support as well, [backdrop](https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter) vs [filter](https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20Filter%20Effects)

Comment: me need blur behind the slide, css filter blur only slide content, this way not fix my problem

Comment: You can blur the slide, and position the layer with content above the slider, that way the content will not be blurred.

Comment: div behind slider not be blurred with blur the slide

Comment: Hi, I've added a working pen :), It's what you needed?

Comment: No, div behind slide not blurred

Answer (score 1):

Use the bellow CSS. the blur effect which is by default in slick slider will be removed.

```
.slick-active{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with this issue. Just disable useTransforms and useCSS in the slider's config object. For example:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4500,
  ladyload: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  useCSS: false,
  useTransform: false
});
```